# How safe is reusing config.cache for cross compilation?

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, configure

Usually, running `./configure --host=xxx` is enough. However, sometimes it is source of very subtle bugs - `./configure` doesn't always complain (and fail) if something is not 100% right.

For instance, it has happened to me more than once that some feature has been just *guessed* and as you can imagine, sometimes that guess wasn't right and the bug (odd behaviour) was spotted much later.

In such cases I solve it by looking into `configure`, writing down the incorrectly guessed variable, checking its correct value on real hardware, putting it into `config.cache` file and restarting the whole process with `--config-cache`.

My question is, how safe is to actually produce the *whole* `config.cache` on real hardware and copy it over to the build machine?

Obviously, the installed libraries must be the same but what about other possible problems -- for instance what if some tool (grep, python etc) is installed on some other place? Or it is missing altogether? Can `./configure` handle this (update its invalid value to a valid/checked one) ?

So far it seems that the only thing needed to update in `config.cache` is `ac_cv_env_host_alias_set` and `setac_cv_env_host_alias_value`, then `./configure` happily continues.

Comment: Can you give a *specific* example of an improperly guessed feature and the resulting specific bug?

Comment: @wallyk: Sure. For instance from bash's ./configure: checking whether integer division by zero raises SIGFPE... guessing yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how safe is to actually produce the whole config.cache
>   on real hardware and copy it over to the build machine?

Not very safe.  Although some of the things `configure` determines and caches are target-system properties, I would expect many to be *build-system* properties, such as details of the cross-compiling toolchain and cross libraries you are using.  You cannot determine such things reliably by running `configure` on the intended host system.  I'm surprised that your efforts in this direction have not run into more trouble than you describe.  That's probably a sign of a cross-development environment that is well-built and -configured for its target.

> Obviously, the installed libraries must be the same

That's probably among the least of the problems with your proposal.

> but what about
>   other possible problems -- for instance what if some tool (grep,
>   python etc) is installed on some other place? Or it is missing
>   altogether?

Yes, if the build requires those or similar tools, then those details are some of the build-system properties that I was talking about.

> Can `./configure` handle this (update its invalid value to a
>   valid/checked one) ?

No.  Where `configure` relies on a cache file, the whole point is that it does not recheck cached results.  You could very likely set that up that kind of thing manually for a project you maintain yourself, but that's not very feasible for third-party code, especially if you're building multiple packages.

I think the bottom line is that cross-compiling is challenging.  Native compiling is to be preferred where possible, even if you need to do it in a virtual environment instead of a physical one.  And if you can successfully run a project's `configure` script in the target environment, then you probably have a native development environment there sufficient for just such a native build.

Comment: Thank you John, that only confirms my assumptions. You are right, my native environment does provide all I need, except speed. :) So I wanted to cheat a little. I had one more idea - to create config.cache and automatically remove everything which contains /bin or /usr/bin references (i.e. build paths). Too bad that config.cache doesn't use variables with build/host/target prefix depending for which part of the build process are needed, that wold make this job a lot of easier. I guess I'll stay in the native environment for now.